# Check Presence of multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check the presence of multiple params.
Currently what i have written is

```
if params[:p1].present? && params[:p2].present? && params[:p3].present?
  # Do something
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `Enumerable.all?` method:

```
%i( p1 p2 p3 ).all? { |key| params[key].present? }
```

Another alternative, if you need the values, it to fetch them and check the presence.

```
params.values_at(*%i( p1 p2 p3 )).all?(&:present?)
```

or

```
params.values_at(:p1, :p2, :p3).all?(&:present?)
```

Comment: "if you need the values" is confusing since you are not saving them to a variable. (Also, there's a small typo in that line.) Presumably, that's the only reason you would favor that approach, as, unlike the first, it obtains all the values even when `false` is returned and creates an array for those values.

Comment: Is it possible to apply that for nested properties? having something like:
`%i( p1 p2 p3.attr ).all? { |key| params[key].present?` }

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you can make use of `Hash#slice` to figure out whether required keys are present in hash.

```
# Below require is needed only in stand-alone program for testing purposes
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'

params = {:p1=>"1", :p2=>"2", :p3 => "3", :p4=>"4"}    
mandatory_keys = [:p1, :p2, :p3]

if (params.slice(*mandatory_keys).values.all?(&:present?)
    puts "All mandatory params present"
else
    puts "Mandatory params missing"
end
```